# format a USB drive that contains Windows OS, but is read-only flile system

Tags: usb, permissions, mount, read-only

Normally, I use GParted, but cannot this time as I will explain.

I have a USB drive that was sent from Dell, containing Windows 8 or 10 (I cannot remember which). I would like to reuse the drive for something useful, but I am getting messages stating that it is read-only.

1. When I attempt to change the permissions of the directory I get `The permissions could not be changed. Sorry, could not change the permissions of 'W8-1': Error setting permissions: Read-only file system.` I have opened nautilus as root.
2. Using the command line: `sudo chown 777 /media/bobo/W8_1/'` I receive the message: `chown: changing ownership of '/media/bobo/W8_1/': Read-only file system`
3. When using gparted, I unmount, select the appropriate drive, unmount drive, select drive to format, choose fat32. Message reads:

   > Can't write to `/dev/sdc` because it is opened read-only.

I have checked the device for a physical switch, but am unable to locate one.

I have wasted enough time on this, I should just throw it away, but am feeling stubborn and would like to get something back for all the time that Microsoft has stolen from me over the years.

Comment: It's a ROM USB drive. There was another question about the same thing, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Might read this link: http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/12/19/how-to-fix-read-only-usb-pen-drive-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Following up, I tried the link from @jpezz and it did not work. In scrolling through the comments, one user stated that they had to run the sequence a few times for it to take, so I may try that. thanks.

Comment: Following up on @wjandrea, I ran a search for "ROM USB drive," and I believe that this correct: The drive in unalterable because it was intended for one use only, as a bootable drive and it appears the manufacturer can lock it as such. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: BTW, if you had succeeded in running `chown 777 /some/path` you would have made the (likely non-existant) user 777 the owner of that file...